# How to consume until a delimiter - with exceptions (Petit Parser for Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, petitparser

Fair enough, previously was a badly worded question. I'm going to take another stab at it.

I'm using Dart's PetitParser to consume input. I want a lexer that will accept any string until one of a number of delimiters is found. The trouble I have is that some of the delimiters are single characters and some are strings, and the characters can be escaped if they're in a single quoted string, and also the delimiters don't count if they're in a single quoted string.

This is my attempted basic setup at the moment:

```dart
Parser<String> fpLexer(List<String> delimiters) {
  return delimiters
      .map(string)
      .toChoiceParser()
      .cast<String>()
      .neg()
      .plus();
}
```

For instance, if my delimiters are `"` and the word `then`. And my input string is:

```
'<a href=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">then</a>' some "Link"
```

I need a Lexer that will consume up until `"Link"`. The reasoning is that the first set of double quotes are within the single quoted segment AND escaped, and because the word `then` is also within the quoted segment, neither of those qualifies as a delimiter. So the first delimiter that's reached is the initial `"` before the word `Link`.

Hopefully I've explained myself better this time. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Your explanation leaves a lot to the imagination. What input is going wrong? Whose at fault here, the ANTLR grammar or the petitparser? Wouldn't it be easier to choose just one tool, instead of (trying) to use them together?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. In Dart I prefer petitparser, because Antlr in Dart doesn't work for PWAs, so I get more flexibility with petitparser. However, the input is from an ANTLR grammar that's standard, so I still have to follow its rules. I'm not using an ANTLR parser at all for this, I'm just trying to mirror it's functionality in petitparser. I'll update my question to include some examples.

Comment: What are "PWAs"? And, what do you mean by "Antlr in Dart doesn't work"?

Comment: Ah, ok, so the question isn't about using ANTLR at all? In that case, you could just remove the ANTLR tag.

Comment: @BartKiers fair point, ANTLR has been removed.

Comment: @kaby76 PWAs are progressive web apps. Dart has the advantage that it can be transpiled into a Javascript Progessive Web app as well as run on a mobile device natively. What I was saying, is that during this process of transpiling, I've run into issues with the ANTLR package for Dart, and it causes errors in the PWA. It works fine in the native applications though.

Answer (score 0):

The examples provided are hard to understand and not minimally reproducible (copy-pastable into the editor), so I am trying to answer the two question I think I can extract.

#### How to consume only as long as another parser accepts?

There are multiple ways to achieve this: There are the logical predicates [and](https://pub.dev/documentation/petitparser/latest/petitparser/AndParser-class.html) and [not](https://pub.dev/documentation/petitparser/latest/petitparser/NotParser-class.html). Furthermore, there are the [lazy](https://pub.dev/documentation/petitparser/latest/petitparser/LazyRepeatingParser-class.html) and [greedy](https://pub.dev/documentation/petitparser/latest/petitparser/GreedyRepeatingParser-class.html) repeaters that consume a parser until another parser succeeds. In the test-case below the parser consumes digits as long as there are two more digits available after the current one (thus the repetition of 3 times):

```dart
final parser = digit().starLazy(digit().repeat(3).not());
expect(parser, isParseSuccess('123', result: ['1'], position: 1));
expect(parser, isParseSuccess('1234', result: ['1', '2'], position: 2));
```

#### How to recognize a list of items with optional delimiters?

This is straightforward, the separated-parser creates a list of elements and separators (where the separator can also be an optional parser):

```dart
final parser = digit().plusSeparated(char(',').optional());
expect(parser, isParseSuccess('1,2,3', result: isSeparatedList<String, String?>(
    elements: ['1', '2', '3'], separators: [',', ','])));
expect(parser, isParseSuccess('12,3', result: isSeparatedList<String, String?>(
    elements: ['1', '2', '3'], separators: [null, ','])));
```